# How can i get email and phone number from contact for current contact?

Tags: java, android, email

code thet get numbers and names of current contact

```
public void test111(View view) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                if (pCur != null) {
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        Logger.log(MainActivity.class, "!!!!!!!!! Name : " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Logger.ERROR);
                    }
                }
                if (pCur != null) {
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but issue in next case, if i need get email from current contact i have to create one more `cursor`

```
Cursor cur1 = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{id}, null);
```

and it give me back list of available email, but not the email for current contact

I need if email available get smth like this `name, number, email` if email not available `name, number, null`